# VB.NET - Тупик с Replace

Tags: vb.net

У меня идет вот такой вот не сложный код:

```
EncryptedText = EncryptedText.Replace("0", " nze ")
EncryptedText = EncryptedText.Replace("1", " non ")
EncryptedText = EncryptedText.Replace("2", " ntw ")
EncryptedText = EncryptedText.Replace("3", " nth ")
EncryptedText = EncryptedText.Replace("4", " nfo ")
EncryptedText = EncryptedText.Replace("5", " nfi ")
EncryptedText = EncryptedText.Replace("6", " nsi ")
EncryptedText = EncryptedText.Replace("7", " nse ")
EncryptedText = EncryptedText.Replace("8", " nei ")
EncryptedText = EncryptedText.Replace("9", " nni ")
EncryptedText = EncryptedText.Replace("a", " 00100 ")
EncryptedText = EncryptedText.Replace("b", " 00101 ")
EncryptedText = EncryptedText.Replace("c", " 00102 ")
EncryptedText = EncryptedText.Replace("d", " 00103 ")
EncryptedText = EncryptedText.Replace("e", " 00104 ")
```

Но в тупик меня ввело то что цифры переводятся в буквы, а после буквы переводятся в цифры и получается тупик. Думал поставить что бы и цифры менялись на цифры, но тогда они просто будут менять друг друга, получается опять тупик. Вопрос - как бы так сделать что бы и цифры и буквы нормально заменялись, при этом не заменяли то что уже заменено. (Запутанно я объяснил...) Впрочем то по коду и так видна проблема. Ищу решение...

Comment: "в тупик меня ввело" - а куда Вы шли? "Запутанно я объяснил" - кто ясно мыслит, ясно излагает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из-за одной буквы "e" столько вони)

```
EncryptedText = EncryptedText.Replace("0", " nz'^' ")
...
EncryptedText = EncryptedText.Replace("7", " ns'^' ")
EncryptedText = EncryptedText.Replace("8", " n'^'i ")
...
EncryptedText = EncryptedText.Replace("e", " 00104 ")
EncryptedText = EncryptedText.Replace("'^'", "e")
```

Но вообще нормальные алгоритмы так не пишутся. Нужно писать алгоритм, который будет искать во входной строке, а писать в выходную.

Comment: "Нужно писать алгоритм, который будет искать во входной строке, а писать в выходную."
А не могли бы вы написать пример? Если вам не сложно.